# Is there a limit on the number of conditional statements in Python?

Tags: python

I was doing some random stuff here just for fun, then I decided to use my free time to port a JavaScript library to Python and I found a issue in the code bellow...

```py
def is_even(number): 
  if (number == "even" or number == "Even" or number == "eVen" or number == "evEn" or number == "eveN" or number == "EVen" or number == "EvEn" or number == "EveN" or number == "eVEn" or number == "eVeN" or number == "evEN" or number == "eVEN" or number == "EvEN" or number == "EVeN" or number == "EVEn" or number == "EVEN"): return True
  elif(number == 1 or number == "1" or number == "one" or number == "One" or number == "ONE"): return False
```

Util the line 5000 it still running okay, just a little slow, but when I use some more, like 300000, the program just doesn't run. Using Pypy3 it says that is a RecursionError

Of course I'm not taking this for real, but I've never seen this error before. So it's interesting to know was is going around and how to fix it. I'm going to still looking for it, however, I'd like to know the opinion from more experienced people.

[Check the original repo](https://github.com/samuelmarina/is-even) if you want. You'd like the Issues and PRs

Here is a print of current work
[image]

Comment: why is the repo for a javascript file and you write python code

Comment: Does it matter? Nobody should write code getting even anywhere close to that.

Comment: what is the need for the `else` statements/text, they can all be deleted, have you considered to use `string.toUpper` or `string.toLower`

Comment: there have been 10 people involved in making this horrible piece of software, that github allows you to upload files of 98MB

Comment: Why write code when you can use an API? https://isevenapi.xyz/

Comment: If I do a simple conversion of that code to Python (similar to what it looks like you've done), I can't run it at all. Python chugs for a while, grabbing about 4 GB of RAM, then crashes and reports `Segmentation fault: 11`. This is on MacOS 10.14.6 with Python 3.8.5. I think this occurs while Python is compiling the script to bytecode -- I get the same message if I run `python -m compileall iseven.py`. So I think this is just a bigger structure than the Python parser can handle.

Comment: About the repo. I just used regex to convert to Python, I don't have one, so I pasted the original for you guys to see.

Comment: and I know it could be better but it is so weird that I could not resist to try in the others languages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python language reference ([relevant part here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement)) doesn't impose any limit on how many `elif` blocks an `if` statement can have, so in the abstract, the *language* doesn't have any such limit.

However, *implementations* of the language such as CPython or PyPy may (and certainly will) have some limits, even if only because computers have finite memory and other storage space. These limits will be well beyond what any sensible program would get near.

This is not at all unusual; for just one other example, the Java Language Specification ([relevant part here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.1)) doesn't impose any limit on how many dimensions an array can have, so in the abstract, the Java *language* has no such limit. But in practice a Java program cannot have a 257-dimensional array. This limit is, likewise, far beyond what any sensible program would get near.